# Is there a mathematical way or algorithm to take a week over week data set gathered daily and convert it to daily data?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-time

I have a large amount of data that was gathered every day.  The data is totals for the past week.

```
2001-01-01 to 2001-01-07 : 27
2001-01-02 to 2001-01-08 : 27
2001-01-03 to 2001-01-09 : 28
2001-01-04 to 2001-01-10 : 26
2001-01-05 to 2001-01-11 : 20
2001-01-06 to 2001-01-12 : 13
2001-01-07 to 2001-01-13 : 14
2001-01-08 to 2001-01-14 : 16
...
...
2006-01-01 to 2006-01-07 : 28
```

My question is whether or not there is some algorithm or mathematical function for figuring out what the values for the individual days were since the data was gathered daily.

If there isn't, I also have the data tallied month over month.

e.g:

```
2001-01-01 to 2001-01-31 : 300
2001-02-01 to 2001-01-28 : 287
2001-03-01 to 2001-01-31 : 322
2001-04-01 to 2001-01-30 : 328
2001-05-01 to 2001-01-29 : 365
```

Is there any formula or algorithm to merge the two data sets to reconcile the daily values?

If this is not the place to ask this question or it should have tags added to help get it to the right audience, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the actual value on at least one day?

Comment: Is each weekly total actually a sum of eight days (i.e. does the first sum include both 1/1 and 1/8)?

Comment: Since you have only have grouped data, it is impossible to reconstruct the values for each day. At most, you can get an approximate value.

Comment: @JustinBarhite thanks for catching that oversight, i'll update the example data, it's 7 days each.

Comment: @EricTowers I do not have the actual value for at least one day except in the case of robert-israel's case in his comment on the first answer where there are weeks with 0 values.

Comment: Then if for any week the value is $0$, that helps you determine the one day before and after that week. This won't guarantee all the values but you'll be able to compute most of them.

Comment: Just a side note: you're data is actually the result of a discrete convolution between the signal you'd like to obtain and a windows or 7 time lapses.

Comment: @Zhuli yes, for any of the data sets that include a zero this becomes trivial, but I'm looking more for a general solution that can be applied to additional data sets as they arise. From everyone else's comments and answers I believe I'm going to end up accepting Justin's answer.  Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @Jeanba It is indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only the weekly totals, it's impossible to recover the individual daily values, since there are six fewer variables than equations. For example, imagine you only had data from 2001-01-01 to 2001-01-09:

```
2001-01-01 to 2001-01-07 : 27
2001-01-02 to 2001-01-08 : 27
2001-01-03 to 2001-01-09 : 28
```

Then you have nine variables (for the nine days) but only three equations. There's no way to distinguish the days 01-03 through 01-07; you can change  these 5 daily values without affecting the weekly totals, as long as you keep the sum of these 5 values the same.

As Robert Israel pointed out in a comment, it seems possible that the additional data of the monthly totals might allow you to determine the exact values for each day. Indeed, with five years of data, you get 60 more equations; it's not obvious to me that (or under what precise conditions) these 60 equations contain six independent equations... but it definitely seems plausible. Some brief experimentation I did in Matlab suggests that you can indeed get up to full rank (and thus recover all the daily values) by adding less than a year's worth of monthly totals.

Comment: But if you assume all values $\ge 0$, which may be reasonable depending on what the data represent, you may be able to do it (e.g. if there was a week where the total was $0$, you would know you had $0$ on each of those days, and you could work backwards and forwards from there).

Comment: Also if you have at least $7$ months (whose number of days is not a multiple of $8$), those may remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I can't convince myself whether (or under what conditions) the additional data of the monthly totals is enough, but with five years of data it seems reasonable (perhaps even likely) that that might happen.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I now believe it is possible to recover all the daily values (using the monthly totals); I've edited my answer to include this.